# Is there a way to ease keyframes as a whole rather than easing each component?

Tags: animation, keyframes, graph-editor

Let's say I've got a cube that spins around and moves, like so: (click for higher quality)

[image]

In the graph editor, it looks like this.

[image]

Each axis of rotation and motion has its own line, but is there a way to manipulate the easing of the keyframe as a whole? It's nice to have the control over all aspects of the animation, but there are times where it's very inconvenient to have to manipulate every single axis to get a simple easing.

In Adobe Flash, you can manipulate the inbetween of two keyframes using this editor, regardless of the amount of scaling, rotation, and translating involved:

[image]

Is there something like that in Blender?

Comment: Are you trying to change Interpolation mode ? (with keyframe/-s *Key* > *Interpolation mode* while in *Graph Editor*)

Comment: @MrZak The problem with that is that it only provides a few preset interpolations, which you can't modify to your liking. Something which would allow you to do that, but customize the curve; that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Basically, those interpolations mods (IM) are the presets of what you could do by yourself. [On this gif](https://i.imgur.com/Dm0Hlf6.gif) I  change IM to Linear, then return it to Bezier and redo the result I've got with Linear. The same thing with Constant, Sinusoidal etc., *but* it will be a little bit more complicated to set up.

Comment: @MrZak Unfortunately, you can only do that to one axis of movement at a time, and there's no way to keep it the same for three different axes on three different keys (LocRotScale).

Comment: What is the problem of selecting / deseleting several points / handles at once ? Then simple [grabbing and scaling them](http://i.imgur.com/TKNtFQi.gif) with Pivot set to `Individual Origins`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Part I.

To move many keyframes at once you can use the Dope Sheet editor instead of the Graph Editor.

[image: Dope Sheet Editor]

In the Dope Sheet editor all actions are represented by little diamond markers. In the above screen shot the column of markers on the right (colored) are selected, and the ones on the left are not selected. Selecting, deselecting, grabbing, etc in this editor works the same way as in Blender's other editors.

Notice the order of hierarchy: The top row is for all objects in the scene. The second row is for just the "Cube" object. The third row "CubeAction" is for actions involving the object, such as LocRotScale transformations (but not for things like Material animation). The fourth row "LocRotScale" contains the actual animation keyframes and if you expand it you will see the individual rows/tracks for Location, Rotation, and Scale for each of the X/Y/Z axes.

So if you want to move just one axis you would expand "LocRotScale", find "X Location" for example and move just its individual marker. But to do what you described - moving all axes at once - you can just leave "LocRotScale" collapsed and drag that marker. All of the animation data will be moved together.

### Part II.

If you want to adjust just the ease of the curves specifically and not their position, you can select the keyframes in the Graph Editor and scale them along only the X axis. Their bezier handles will be moved closer to or farther from the keyframe points, thus altering the ease.

As a variation of this you can try scaling with the Pivot Point set to Individual Centers. You may find that scaling and rotating from individual centers gives you more control than simply scaling along X.

[image]

Comment: Although it's not the best thing, this method definitely works. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean and I agree. It's not ideal, but it's workable.